# adjective for something that is consisted of parts that are not in any kind of accord with each other

Tags: word-request

What would be the correct adjective in English to describe something in which its constituent parts don't agree with and don't correspond to each other?

For example, the dance routine didn't correspond to the chosen music, and neither music, nor the dance went along with the slogan for the overall school's performance. So you would say, "This class's performance was absolutely ______________________."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It was a **hodgepodge** (of themes and styles).*

It know it's a noun, but it directly means that nothing matches anything else, whereas "shambolic" just means disorganized or falling apart.

There's no adjectival form of hodgepodge that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

It was *a shambles*.

A shambles is a state of chaotic disorder. It would imply the lack of organisation or consistency described in your example.

The derived adjective is "shambolic"

Comment: interesting etymology, from "low bench or stool used for displaying produce" to "market in which produce is displayed on benches" to specifically "meat market", to its modern sense.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be okay to say "The performance was absolutely a shambles"?

Comment: The performance was absolutely shambolic.

Comment: @Sam but is it also okay to say "was absolutely a shambles"?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to say 'it was a shambles'. _Shambolic_ is a colloquial term derived from the noun.

Comment: @JamesK - I thought the original meaning of _shambles_ was a slaughterhouse?

Comment: @KateBunting - I know it's okay to say "It was a shambles" (from the very first line of the answer), but I mean is it okay to say in English "It was absolutely a shambles"?

Comment: I would probably say "It was an absolute shambles".

Comment: @KateBunting - I see. Thank you!

Comment: Slaugherhouse is actually a later, derived meaning.  If you go to York, you can go to the Shambles, and see the shops with "benches" (they look like large windowsills but on the outside) These were used for laying out produce (particularly meat) for sale There was still a butchers in the Shambles when I lived there, but most of the shops are little boutiques. And so the meaning transferred from "bench" to meat market, and from meat market to slaughterhouse.

Comment: @JamesK "There was still a butchers in the Shambles when I lived there, but most of the shops are little boutiques" - Why do they not sell meat anymore?